# Xamarin Community Toolkit TabView - Navigate within Tabs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

For the bottom navigation bar, I'm using a Tabbed Page, and inside of a Tabbed page, I'm using a Tabview from the Xamarin Community Toolkit. On each XCT tab, I'm loading a list of items using the collection view (Xamarin Community Toolkit TabView).  I need to click an item in collection view and  move to another page (detail page) within the same tab of the tabbed page. Although I am aware that Shell might be used, I prefer to use the method described above.

[image]

Comment: the child of the TabbedPage should be wrapped in a NavigationPage, then you can use that page's Navigation property to `PushAsync(new SecondPage())`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SelectionChangedCommand` to bind with the `ItemSelectedCommand` command and then use `Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());` to navigate to the detail page  as Jason suggested.

Here's the code snippet below for your reference:

```
INavigation Navigation => Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation;

public ICommand ItemSelectedCommand
  {
     get
     {
         return new Command(async () =>
         {
             if (SelectedItem == null) return;

             if(SelectedItem.Id ==1)
             {
                  await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());
             }
             //else if
             SelectedItem = null;
          });
       }
   }
```